# log location in db2

Tags: db2

Where are log file stored in DB2?

I am searching for a file with name *Updatedb20100604182008.log*

Comment: This is not a log file generated by the DB2 engine.  What generated this log file?

Comment: If you are asking about **application** logs, all the answers below for sure will crash your database if you do not want to remove **transaction** logs. Deleting manually any of these files will certainly create havoc in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this page:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0301kline/0301kline.html

(The article goes into further detail about default locations as well.)

> The database logs are initially
>   created in a directory called
>   SQLOGDIR, a sub-directory of the
>   database directory. You can change the
>   location where active logs and future
>   archive logs are placed by changing
>   the value for this configuration
>   parameter to point to either a
>   different directory, or to a device.
>   Archive logs that are currently stored
>   in the database log path directory are
>   not moved to the new location if the
>   database is configured for
>   roll-forward recovery.
>
> Because you can change the log path
>   location, the logs needed for
>   roll-forward recovery may exist in
>   different directories or on different
>   devices. You can change this
>   configuration parameter during the
>   roll-forward process to allow you to
>   access logs in multiple locations.
>
> The change to the value of newlogpath
>   will not be applied until the database
>   is in a consistent state. An
>   informational database configuration
>   parameter, database_consistent,
>   indicates the status of the database.
>
> Note: The database manager writes to
>   transaction logs one at a time. The
>   total size of transactions that can be
>   active is limited by the database
>   configuration parameters:

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 log file location can be found from the DB CFG parameter - **'Path to log files'**.

The command would be the below, without an explicit connection to the DB.

> db2 get db cfg for db_name | grep 'Path to log files'

Else, you can connect to the DB first and use the command as follows:-

> ```
> db2 connect to db_name
> db2 get db cfg | grep 'Path to log files'
> db2 terminate
> ```

Answer (score -1):

1. `db2 connect to database`
2. `db2 get db cfg | grep -i log`
3. `cd /data/dblogs/NODE0000`(path to the log files)
4. `cd LOGSTREAM0000`(these is log folder)
5. `ls -altr`(we can see all the log files with .log extension)
6. `rm abc.log` (give the log name which you want to delete)